# Easy way to determine the stationary distribution for Markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose we have the following Markov chain with $S=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}$

[image]

With the given transition matrix

$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1/6 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$

The stationary distribution is given by

$$\pi P=\pi$$

For our case we have

$$(x_1,\ldots,x_7)\cdot P=(x_1,\ldots,x_7)$$

with $\sum_{i=1}^7x_i=1 \ \ \ \text{(1.0)}$

That would mean we have a large system of linear equations with a constraint (1.0). That would be hard to calculate it. Is there an easy way to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Markov chain is reversible, as is any finite Markov chain whose underlying graph is a tree; like all reversible finite Markov chains, it can be viewed as random walk on a weighted graph.

If you give the edges $\{e,c\}$, $\{e,f\}$, $\{e,g\}$ each weight $3$, and the other edges weight $1$, then at each step the walker is choosing from the neighbors of its current state with probability proportional to the weight on that edge.

For a random walk on a weighted graph, the stationary distribution at a vertex is proportional to the sum of the weights of the edges at that vertex (loops only count once, but there aren't any in this example). Here we get $$\frac{1}{24}(1,1,6,1,9,3,3)$$ Note that $24$ is twice the sum of the edge weights.

Page 63 of [Aldous-Fill](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/RWG/book.pdf) writes this down in general (as, I'm sure, does your textbook).

Comment: But I why do you assign the edge weight 3 to $\{e,f\},\{e,c\},\{e,g\}$ and the other edges weight 1? I don't understand why we change the given edge weights in the given transition matrix.

Comment: Because they're the weights that lead to the given transition probabilitiies. The key assignments are at vertex $c$; because you're three times as likely to go from $c$ to $e$ as to $a$, $b$, or $d$, the weight on $\{c,e\}$ must be three times as large as the weight on each of $\{c,a\}$, $\{c,b\}$, or $\{c,d\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Just to indicate another interpretation to the answer above, consider
that the given Transition Matrix actually consists of three blocks
 - A) $x_1, x_2, x_4 \; \to \; x_3$  with probability $1$, and from $x_3$ back to 
$x_1, x_2, x_4$ with the same probability of $1/6$ for each passage;
 - B)  $x_6, x_7 \; \to \; x_5$  with probability $1$, and from $x_5$ back to 
$x_6, x_7$ with the same probability of $1/3$ for each passage;
 - C)  a transition between block $A)$ and block $B)$ above,  which occurs through
the elements $x_3, x_5$, and which has a transition matrix given by
$$
{\bf M} = \left( {\matrix{
   {1/2} & {1/2}  \cr 
   {1/3} & {2/3}  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$

Then it is clear that in block $C$ we will have an equilibrium at $x_3/x_5= 2/3$.
In block $A$ the equilibrium will mean $x_1 /x_3= x_2 /x_3=x_4 /x_3=1/6$,
and in block $B$ the equilibrium will mean $x_6 /x_5= x_7 /x_5=1/3$.

That means that the equilibrium vector will be 
$$(1,1,6,1,9,3,3)/24$$
which is in fact the (left) eigenvector of the transition matrix corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not that hard to calculate directly. The stationary distributions are left eigenvectors of $1$, i.e., (transposed) elements of the null space of $$(I-P)^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&-\frac16&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&-\frac16&0&0&0&0 \\ -1&-1&1&-1&-\frac13&0&0 \\ 0&0&-\frac16&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&-\frac12&0&1&-1&-1 \\ 0&0&0&0&-\frac13&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&-\frac13&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$ This matrix is quite sparse and has $1$s running down its main diagonal, so row-reduction proceeds pretty quickly, resulting in $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&-\frac13 \\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&-\frac13 \\ 0&0&1&0&0&0&-2 \\ 0&0&0&1&0&0&-\frac13 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&0&-3 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&1&-1 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix},$$ from which we find that the null space is the span of $\left(\frac13,\frac13,2,\frac13,3,1,1\right)^T$, which normalizes to the stationary distribution $\frac1{24}(1,1,6,1,9,3,3)$.